# New to Mozilla SDK, "url is undefined" error

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I just installed mozilla sdk. I am trying to get the first example program to work but keep getting the error: "JavaScript error: chrome://browser/content/urlbarBindings.xml, line 648: aUrl is undefined".Same thing when I run cfx testall

For reference the program is:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
  tabs.open("https://developer.mozilla.org/");
}
```

Any ideas what could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the question is still relevant, but i solved similar problem by installing newer sdk version from [Developer Hub](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder).